# Automatically updating boolean value

Tags: java, boolean, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Context:
https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/4wqzph/20160808_challenge_278_easymed_weave_insert_part_1/

Full Code: 
http://pastebin.com/UghV3xdT

I have 2 practically identical methods that can only different by one if-statement: `if (k % 3 != 1)` and `if(k % 2 == 0)`.

```
int k = 0;
while(k<50){
    if(k % 3 != 1){ // OR if(k % 2 == 0)
        // Code logic goes here
    k++;
    }
}
```

The use of each cases is determined by the length of an Array which means the specific case only has to be determined 1 time. 'k' represents the index of another array and 50 is the length of this Array.

I could write something like `if(foo > 1 ? k % 3 != 1 : k % 2 == 0)` but that requires the program to do the action every time the loop runs.

In a way I would like a sort of updating boolean. Is there any way to do this, or is this the downside of pass-by-value? Should I keep two seperate methods or am I better of with using the ternary operator?

In essence I'm looking for a type that contains the expression rather than the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java 8 there is nice functional interface called `IntPredicate`. If you combine it with lambda expressions, you can achieve your goal with no duplication, extra code or any slow downs:

```
public final class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Instead of randomly choosing the predicate, use your condition here
        Random random = new Random();
        IntPredicate intPredicate = random.nextBoolean() ? i -> i % 2 == 0 : i -> i % 3 != 1;

        int k = 0;
        while(k<50){
            /*
             *At this point the predicate is either k%2==0 or k%3!=1,
             * depending on which lambda you assigned earlier.
             */
            if(intPredicate.test(k)){ 
                // Code logic goes here
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Please not that I use the random boolean value to switch between the predicates, but you can use whatever condition you have

Comment: This answer is fine assuming the OP can and wants to use Java 8.

Comment: It is applicable to java < 8 , then one just have to write down the interface and use for instance an  anonymous class instead of lambda

Comment: Of course, assuming Java 8 is extremely reasonable. Java 7 is past end-of-life, and Java 9 will soon be here.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @TomMartens Hi, please accept the answer if you think this is the right solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two different classes that have the same function and then use one of it. For example, out of the loop:

```
class A{ bool calc(int n){return n%3 != 1} }
class B{ bool calc(int n){return n%2 == 0} }
Object x = (foo > 1 ? new A():new B());
```

Then you can use in the loop only `x.calc(k)`.

Comment: This is no different than his original solution with the ternary operator

Comment: This is different that the original solution; note the words, *"out of the loop."* This is just the pre-lambda rendition of `IntPredicate`.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see any way to simplify the logic of your ternary expression in a clever way.  But if you place the logical check outside the `while` loop over `k`, then you will only have to make the check once:

```
int k = 0;

if (foo > 1) {
    while (k < 50) {
        if (k % 3 != 1) {
            // code logic goes here
        }
        k++;
    }
}
else {
    while (k < 50) {
        if (k % 2 == 0) {
            // code logic goes here
        }
        k++;
    }
}
```

This isn't beautiful code, but it frees you from having to use a ternary expression in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: He can still make the check once, and still have a single loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38920956/2588800 :)

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 allows many variants:

```
IntConsumer businessLogic = (k) -> { ... };
```

Or make a method and use `::businessLogic`.

```
if (foo) {
    IntStream.range(0, 50)
        .filter(k % 3 != 1)
        .forEach(businessLogic);
} else {
    IntStream.range(0, 50)
        .filter(k % 2 == 0)
        .forEach(businessLogic);
}
```

Purely a matter of taste, but I like to see the hard numeric constants together.
Of course one may write:

To have a loop without condition for the test:

```
IntStream is = IntStream.range(0, 50);
is = ... ? is.filter(k % 3 != 1) : is.filter(k % 2 == 0);
is.forEach(businessLogic); // Only now one iterates.
```